# Why variables related to visual mode start with two uppercase letters in Vim source code?

Tags: visual-mode

In Vim sources, a lot of variables related to visual mode start with two uppercase letters:

```
EXTERN bool VIsual_active INIT(= false);
EXTERN bool VIsual_select INIT(= false);
EXTERN int VIsual_select_reg INIT(= 0);
```

[Here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/c0ac53e0d6a1e1fab38738e549200975ac0128a3/src/nvim/globals.h#L535C1-L535C41) is the example on GitHub.

What is the reason for that? Is it a small reference to the Vi editor?

Comment: I'm afraid the only person that could answer died a couple of weeks ago. FWIW, a) vi didn't have visual mode so that would be a strange place for a wink, b) the name "vi" is not generally capitalized, and c) "ex" is never capitalized in macro or variable names.

Comment: > I'm afraid the only person that could answer died a couple of weeks ago.

Yes, I also think so, but still, I decided to try my luck.

Comment: You could try `git log -G VI` or similar and try to find the first references; maybe it's explained there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are pointers in [`version.c`](https://github.com/vim/vim-history/blob/d094693f625e9dda1344b25a8a036d741b9a7fbf/src/version.c#L513-L518) of `v2.4`:

> Included code to save the xterm title. Need to define USE_X11, because
> specific include file and library are needed.
>
> Added 'icon' option (default off): when set xterm icon is set to file name.
>
> Changed Visual into VIsual, because it is also used by X11.

There may be a relevant header file `/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h`
on a *nix box with a `Visual` structure, which can be included
in [`unix.c`](https://github.com/vim/vim-history/blob/d094693f625e9dda1344b25a8a036d741b9a7fbf/src/unix.c#L303-L305):

```c
#ifdef USE_X11

# include <X11/Xlib.h>
```

To learn more about `X11R5` `Visual` types, see its [`tar`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R5/mit-4.tar.Z)r'd
documentation, where `Visual` types are described. Read
the second paragraph of `mit/doc/Xlib/CH03` file:

```shell
tar xf mit-4.tar.Z
man -l mit/doc/Xlib/CH03
```

Comment: You want me to dowload a file, untar it and open it in `man` just so I can read its second paragraph? Couldn't you just have pasted that paragraph in the answer?

Comment: Why, only if you're curious about `X11` of the day; otherwise, finding `Visual` in `X11/Xlib.h` should be enough to arrive at the contextual contingency for a name clash.

Comment: Awesome research!

Answer (score 4):

It appears first in vim-2.4 (July 1994), was not in vim-2.0 (December 1993).  There are no comments about this, but seeing that "Visual" and "visual" are used in the comments, it likely was a convenient way to allow grepping for the related symbols without seeing the comments at the same time.

Git doesn't go back far enough, by about ten years.  Nor CVS (see the vile FAQ: [*When did development begin?*](https://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.faq.html#clone_began)).

Vim's pre-CVS history is just [tarballs](http://ftp.vim.org/ftp/vim/old/).

For further reading: [*When was visual-mode introduced?*](https://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.faq.html#clone_visual)